# CSS reset only table border properties?

Tags: html, css

Many borders in a HTML table seems overlapping thus creating pseudo-double borders for some of the cells. It looks awful, especially when the table is collapsed in mobile devices.

Is there a way to reset all the css border directives for tables to try to recreate them in another way for Desktops and mobile?

Is there something recommended that works well in all cases?

Comment: The *Ask a question*  page says **Provide details. Share your research.** for a reason.

Comment: Here is a link to the [guides](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<style>
* {
  border: initial !important;
  border-width: initial !important;
  border-color: initial !important;
  border-style:  initial !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **initial** (along with **!important** keyword) value to the borders of the content. This will set **border** property to its default value. So your overlapping problems will be gone.

Here's the Syntax-

```
yourTable{
 border: initial !important;
 border-style: initial !important;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, please let me know with your code. :)